# Как работает NSNotification?

Tags: swift

В данный момент я использую `NSNotification` для того чтобы, когда я возвращаюсь со второго контроллера на первый (для примера), то первый выполнял бы какое либо действия, если на втором было совершенно действие. Первый контроллер разумеется, наблюдает за данным уведомлением. Все работает. Проблема в том, что лид говорит, что `NSNotification` могут получить любые контролеры, которые даже не наблюдают за данным уведомлением, к примеру что это уведомление может получить четвертый контроллер, который по сути вообще ничего не знает об этом уведомление. Я читал документацию, там про это ничего не было сказано и не разу с этим не сталкивался. Правда ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую объяснить на пальцах.

`NSNotificationCenter` это синглтон, который фактически умеет делать две вещи:

- зарегистрировать любой обратившийся класс обсервером для любого нотификейшена. При этом класс передает имя нотификейшена, метод, который надо выполнить и дополнительную информацию, например объект идентификатор.
- любой класс может запостить любой нотификейшн, при этом `NSNotificationCenter` пройдется по своему массиву всех зарегистрировавшихся, и каждому кто зарегистрировался обсервером на данный нотификейшн отправит на выполнение соответствующий метод.

Как вы видите, если ваш класс не зарегистрировался, он понятия не имеет какие нотификейшены ходят по системе, и даже если что-то где то начнет сбоить, то `NSNotificationCenter` понятия не имеет какие методы есть у конкретного класса, чтобы их вызвать.

Comment: Я знал, что отправляется только на конкретную нотификацию, но лидер мне говорил обратное...

Comment: очень хочется написать гадость. но не буду :)

Comment: На счёт меня? Можете высказать своё мнение, я не обижусь. Критика помогает расти

Comment: на счет вашего лида. уж дизайн паттерны лид должен знать. могу вам предложить на досуге написать свою имплементацию нотификейшенов, займет это у вас от силы час, зато поймете весь процесс изнутри

Comment: Извините, но хочу у вас спросить ваш аккаунт Skype, если это можно. Мне спросить пару конфликтных вопроса, так как я например делаю один метод, лидер говорит неправильно, далее ищу информацию в сети или спрашиваю, люди советуют так же как я делал, но это все равно не подходит лидеру.

Comment: не хочу тут постить, но вы его без труда найдете на основании моего имени :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34977/discussion-between-alexsander-and-max-mikheyenko).